# Do Python modules need shebangs or encoding directives?

Tags: python

our application is composed of several modules grouped in two packages, and one script.
I am not sure, and don't manage to google my way through to knowing if the modules need a coding directive in order to manage our native french accented strings, and while we're at it, a shabang with the interpreter directive, or if it is enough to put these two lines in the one script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scripts need shebangs. Modules don't need shebangs -- they're sometimes used to make text editors' jobs easier (in detecting the programming language easier), or if a module can be run as a script to execute its tests, but are not called for otherwise.

All Python code, whether in modules or scripts, should have encoding directives when not using the default encoding for the Python version targeted (ASCII for 2.x, Unicode for 3.x).

Answer (score 2):

Scripts need shebangs iff they will be executable. That is, you need a shebang if you intend to run them as `script` (or `script.py`) but not if you intend to run them as `python script.py`.

That's really the only use case for shebangs. Editors may also use them to determine mode, but they should also look at the `.py` extension.

The default source encoding for Python 2 is ASCII. To put any non-ASCII string literals in a Python 2 source file you should have a line such as this as the first or second line of the file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

You can of course substitute a different encoding but utf-8 is common. It's been pointed out to me that the `-*-` can be left out and are for some shell compatibility reason, but the docs include them.

The default source encoding for Python 3 is utf-8, so go ahead and use all the characters.

Comment: +1 for a better, more in-depth description of encoding behavior than what my answer included. That said, I'd argue that a script should just be `yourscript`, not `yourscript.py` -- more compliant with platform convention; you run `ls`, not `ls.elf`, after all. Indeed, when setuptools is being used to automatically build script wrappers for entry points, it avoids using extensions except where the platform requires otherwise for the same reason.

Comment: Good point, my python bin scripts don't have an extension either